# How to change the location of a JTextArea at run-time?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextarea

[SOLVED]
I am using Swing, I have a JPanel and in it there is a JTextArea and a JButton. I want the JTextArea to move when the button is clicked on. I'm Not really sure how to do the action listener for the button. At the moment the JTextArea only moves once when the button is clicked on, but i want it to move every time the button is clicked on.

this is what i have so far:
    `x = 20`
    `moveButton = new JButton("MOVE");`
    `moveButton.setName("move");`
    `moveButton.setBounds(20, 140, 70, 40);`

```
text = new JTextArea("-->");
text.setEditable(false);
text.setBounds(x, 50, 40, 20);

panel.add(moveButton);
panel.add(text);
```

In the actionPerformed method this is what it does:

```
text.setBounds(x + 50, 50, 40, 20);
panel.add(text);
text.setVisible(true);
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

I have also posted this question on:  [Java-Fourms](http://www.java-forums.org/swing-codes/85365-how-change-location-jtextarea-run-time.html)

Comment: Maybe a better question is _why_ you want it to move. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I have a list of Jlabels and I want to move the Jtextarea (like a pointer) when new jlabels are added to the list the jtextarea points to the new label...I am creating a queue visualization.

Comment: Take a look at the [Drag and Drop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) trail, maybe you can find something there will help you out.

Comment: thank you for responding its fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of x variable? We need more code to be able to help you.

What i suspect is, you are not incrementing x and constantly moving to the same location.

For example, if x = 30 and you move to x+50 it will always go to 80.
So you could also increase x in button listener - something like x += 50;

Comment: your right, I wasnt increasing x so thats why it wasnt moving more than once. that works thank you for your help.